# Generating a string with dynamic input

Tags: python

![Text]   I would like to generate a string with input from a list but I am having trying inputting data from a list without repetition.any help will be appreciated

````
def populateFlat2():
    f=open("ESflat.txt","w")
    events=['one','two','three','four'];
    for s in events:
       for i in range(0,1):
           for j in range(0,5):
               string=("{},".format(i)+"20200101 8:0{},".format(j)+s+",S1"+"\n");
               f.write(string)
#DesireOutput:
#0,20200101 8:00,one,S1
#0,20200101 8:01,two,S1
#0,20200101 8:02,three,S1
#0,20200101 8:03,four,S1
#1,20200101 8:00,one,S1
#1,20200101 8:01,two,S1
#1,20200101 8:02,three,S1
#1,20200101 8:03,four,S1

populateFlat2()```
````

Answer (score -1):

for the desire input, you need to use the python inbuilt function `enumerate`

```
def populateFlat2():

    events=['one','two','three','four'];
    with open("ESflat.txt","a+") as f:
        for index, data in enumerate(events):

            string = "{},20200101 8:0{},{},{}\n".format(0, index, data, 'S1')
            f.write(string)

#DesireOutput:
#0,20200101 8:00,one,S1
#0,20200101 8:01,two,S1
#0,20200101 8:02,three,S1
#0,20200101 8:03,four,S1
populateFlat2()
```

imporvement in your code

your code is not giving correct output because of the innermost for loop you are using, instead of using a for look to count the no, you can add a variable which store the line no , below is sample improved code

```
def populateFlat2():
    f=open("ESflat.txt","w")
    events=['one','two','three','four'];
    check = 0 
    for s in events:
       for i in range(0,1):
               string=("{},".format(i)+"20200101 8:0{},".format(check)+s+",S1"+"\n");
               f.write(string)
               check+=1
#DesireOutput:
#0,20200101 8:00,one,S1
#0,20200101 8:01,two,S1
#0,20200101 8:02,three,S1
#0,20200101 8:03,four,S1
populateFlat2()
```